# JS: join()-ing an array of objects

Tags: javascript

Say I have an array of objects that I want to be able to access as hashes sometimes (to change their values, eh?) and sometimes print.

```
var test = { members : [] };
test.addMember = function(name, value) { 
    this.members[name] = { name : name, value : value }; 
    this.members[name].toString = function() { 
        return this.name + " has a " + this.value; };
};
test.toString = function() { 
    return this.members.join(" and ");
};
test.addMember("a", "a value");
test.addMember("b", "b value");
alert(test);
```

My Goal here is to have test.toString() return:

```
a has a value and b has b value
```

or what-have-you. I was reading on the MDN, and it seems that JavaScript 1.8.5 (or some subrevision) will have a join() that calls toString(). Am I stuck?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's my FINAL design, with a modify and delete function included (in case anyone was curious)!

```
var test = { 
    members : [],
    modifyMember : function(name, value) {
        var index = this.members.indexOf(this.members[name]);
        if(index < 0) {
            return;
        }
        this.members[index].value = this.members[name].value = value;
    },
    addMember : function(name, value) { 
        if(this.members[name]) { 
            this.modifyMember(name, value);
            return;
        }
        this.members[name] = { 
            name : name, 
            value : value,
            toString : function() { 
                return this.name + " has " + this.value; 
            },
        }; 
        this.members.push(this.members[name]);
    },
    removeMember : function(name) { 
        if(!this.members[name]) return;
        this.members.splice(this.members.indexOf(this.members[name]), 1);
        delete this.members[name];
    },
    toString : function() {
        return this.members.join(" AND ");
    } 
};
```

Comment: or rather `a has a a value and b has a b value`?

Comment: Well... yes. That's exactly what I meant.

Comment: I like both stewe's answer and gilly3's answer. Stewe's involves a bit more processing, and gilly3's a bit more memory usage. I've decided that I'll be using gilly3's, but I wanted to thank everyone for such quick answers. Thanks for making my first question posted to stackoverflow one that will have me back again! Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already expanding your Array with properties.  Now, just don't forget to populate your Array.  Use `Array.push()`:

```
test.addMember = function(name, value) { 
    this.members[name] = { name : name, value : value }; 
    this.members.push(this.members[name]);
    ...
};
```

Comment: +1 @mpw: thats it. just push the object to your array. otherwise you will lose them.

Comment: You should avoid adding the expando altogether, a better solution is to simply added the object directly, and deal with duplicates in a different manner.

Comment: So adding a keyed value allows me (of course) keyed access, but breaks join().

Pushing the object onto the array breaks my ability to access via key (though I could create a method to fake it) but allows join.

Doing both seems to break iteration though, which I would prefer to avoid.

Comment: @mpw - It doesn't "break" join.  Those "keyed values" are actually properties on the Array - not part of the collection.  Join worked correctly - your Array was empty, so an empty string was returned.  If you are iterating via `for..in`, I would advise against it.  Just iterate the Array using [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/array/foreach) or a regular `for` loop.  Iteration should not be broken.

Comment: @gilly3 - When I typed break, I meant for my purposes. I suppose that what I think of as a "key-value array" is just an "array with properties." join() doesn't include functions or properties, and it would be a less useful function if it did.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be: (members is an object)

```
var test = { members : {} };
test.addMember = function(name, value) { 
    this.members[name] = { name : name, value : value }; 
    this.members[name].toString = function() { 
        return this.name + " has a " + this.value; };
};
test.toString = function() {
    var arr=[];
    for(var i in this.members) {
        if (this.members.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            arr.push(this.members[i].toString());
        }
    }
    return arr.join(" and ");
};
test.addMember("a", "a value");
test.addMember("b", "b value");
alert(test.toString());
```

And another way (members is an array):

```
var test = { members : [] };
test.addMember = function(name, value) { 
    var arr= { name : name, value : value }; 
    arr.toString = function() { 
        return this.name + " has a " + this.value; 
    };
    this.members.push(arr);
};
test.toString = function() { 
    return this.members.join(" and ");
};
test.addMember("a", "a value");
test.addMember("b", "b value");
alert(test.toString());
```

Comment: I suppose the real best solution depends on whether I'll be doing more accessing a specific test.member via its name property, or printing it via string. I s'pose that accessing via name (members-is-an-array) will require a MAX of N loops to find my value, whereas toString-ing by creating a temporary array requires ALWAYS N loops. The array idea sure seems more efficient!